# Write an object oriented program that randomly generates an array of 1000 integers between 1 to 1000

Tags: java, arrays, oop

this code doesn't function,
it said that lessthaAverage(int) in calculateArray cannot be applied to (), I'm a beginner so I still don't understand this coding yet, this is the question ask, Write an object oriented program that randomly generates an array of 1000 integers between 1 to 1000.
Calculate the occurrences of number more than 500 and find the average of the numbers. 
Count the number which is less than the average and finally sort the numbers in descending order.
Display all your output. Please do HELP ME!!!,Thank You...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
//import java.util.random;

public class CalculateArray
{
    //declare attributes
    private int arr[] = new int[1000];
    int i;


    //generates an array of 1000 integers between 1 to 1000
    public void genArr()
    {
        Random ran = new Random();  

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = ran.nextInt(1000) + 1;

        }

    }

    //Calculate the occurences of number more than 500
    public int occNumb()
    {
       int count;
       for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
       {
           if(arr[i] > 500) 
           {
               count++;

           }
       }

       return count;
    }

    //find the average of the numbers
    public int average()
    {
        int sum, aver;

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            sum += arr[i];

        }
        aver = sum/1000;

        return aver;
    }

    //Count the number which is less than the average
    public int lessthanAverage(int aver)
    {
        int cnt;
        cnt = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] < aver)
            {
                cnt++;
            }
        }

        return cnt;
    }

    //finally sort the numbers in descending order.
    public void sort(int[] num)
    {

        System.out.println("Numbers in Descending Order:" );


    for (int i=0; i <= num.length; i++)
        for (int x=1; x <= num.length; x++)
            if (num[x] > num[x+1])
            {
                int temp = num[x];
                num[x] = num[x+1];
                num[x+1] = temp;
            }
    }

    //Display all your output

    public void display()
    {
         int count, aver;
         System.out.println(arr[i] + " ");
         System.out.println("Found " + count + " values greater than 500");
         System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + aver);
         System.out.println("Found " + count + " values that less than average number ");
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CalculateArray show = new CalculateArray();

        show.genArr();
        int c= show.occNumb();
        show.average();
        int d=show.lessthanAverage();
        show.sort(arr);
        show.display();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: What is the error you are having exactly?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you shouldn't be instantiating a new `Random` object with every call to `genArr()`.  Make `ran` static and instantiate it once, for instance in main or statically at the class declaration level.

Comment: The method is defined with parameter public int lessthanAverage(int aver), however when you use it in main method. You do not pass a value. There should be a complier error. In addition, for the attribute arr (private int arr[] = new int[1000];), it is non-static. You can not use it directly in main method, which is a static method. There will be a complier error as well.

Comment: Is there some reason you're writing your own sort rather than using `Arrays.sort`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
To learn how to ask a good question see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @pjs: A beginner *should* write their own sort, list, stack, queue, etc, etc. I don't understand why those questions are even posed.

Comment: @BobbyDigital Eventually, yes.  But beginners should also learn to use library capabilities.  If writing a sort is not part of the assignment, using Java's sort seems to me the better choice, hence I raised in as a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your method lessthanAverage is expecting a int parameter.  You should store the result of the average method call into a int variable and pass it to the call to lessthanAverage.

```
   int avg = show.average();
   int d=show.lessthanAverage(avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `lessthaAverage()` method expects an average to be passed in as a parameter, but you are not passing it in when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your method `lessthanAverage` needs an `int` as a parameter, but you are not passing it in `main`

```
public int lessthanAverage(int aver)
```

In main `aver` is not being passed:

```
int d=show.lessthanAverage();  // where is aver?
```

But if you wanted to know the average inside the method you could call your `average` method inside `lessthanAverage`:

```
if(arr[i] < this.average())
```

and not pass any parameter at all:

```
public int lessthanAverage()
```